# Stata foreach not generating output

Tags: foreach, stata

```
foreach x in 1:3 {
gen VAR`x'TEST = .
}
```

I wish to create loop that makes VARIABLES: VAR1TEST, VAR2TEST, VAR3TEST but this generates only a variable called V1

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that works at all and especially surprised that `V1` is created.

You can use `foreach` to cycle over a list of integers in various ways, and here are two.

```
foreach x in 1 2 3 { 

foreach x of num 1/3 {
```

but for what you want it's more direct (and more efficient) to go

```
forval x = 1/3 {
```